# Access link tables not showing all records

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Ive set up a obdc connection in access to my sql server and ive linked the tables to the tables in sql but when i open the linked tables they didn't pull all of the records from the source tables and when i enter new records they only show in the original table and not the linked table.

[image: Picture showing original and linked tables]

Comment: Looks like you have two tables. A local one called `dbo_Clients` and a link table that is `dbo_Clients1`. Those are two unrelated tables, so I would suspect that if you enter data into the local one it won't show up in the link table. Get rid of your local table if your intentions are to only use the link table from your server.

Comment: is there any way to link the two tables because when i delete the local tables the forms and queries no longer work

Comment: Perhaps what you can try (I'm not certain that it will work, but I'm like 80%...) is delete the local table and then rename the link table to the same as the local. Then perhaps the forms and queries will be happy and pointed to the remote table as they ought to be.

Comment: @Gavin What is your experience with ODBC connections?

Answer (score 0):

do you need a linked and a local table?

Change the recordsource property of the form to the dbo_Clients1 table. That way any changes you make will reflect in SQL server when the form is saved.